# What exactly is a stream in java? And how are they related to Lambda-Expressions?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I just don't get it. What are streams, how to use them and how to use Lambda expressions with it?

Comment: Search the web for tutorials. For example: [Processing Data with Java SE 8 Streams, Part 1](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/ma14-java-se-8-streams-2177646.html), and [Part 2](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/architect-streams-pt2-2227132.html). You can also find many videos about this on YouTube.

Comment: thank you @Jesper, im studieng this pages and hope they'll help me

Answer (score 2):

From the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html):

> A sequence of elements supporting sequential and parallel aggregate
>   operations

I think the below is key, however. The stream is making the elements of the collection available for the downstream operations.

> A stream pipeline, like the "widgets" example above, can be viewed as
>   a query on the stream source. Unless the source was explicitly
>   designed for concurrent modification (such as a ConcurrentHashMap),
>   unpredictable or erroneous behavior may result from modifying the
>   stream source while it is being queried.

Note also:

> Collections and streams, while bearing some superficial similarities,
>   have different goals. Collections are primarily concerned with the
>   efficient management of, and access to, their elements. By contrast,
>   streams do not provide a means to directly access or manipulate their
>   elements, and are instead concerned with declaratively describing
>   their source and the computational operations which will be performed
>   in aggregate on that source

If you're at all familiar with Scala (and noting its apparent absence of streams), it would be worth looking at [this article](https://dzone.com/articles/java-8-vs-scalapart-ii-streams-api) too, which details the collection/stream differences, with particular focus on Java vs. Scala.